# AutoCompleteTextView suggestions can't be updated?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change a list of suggestions for AutoCompleteTextView depending on an option choosen in another View (Spinner). Unfortunately it seems that the adapter of this TextView isn't notified from within the setOnClickListener method of another View. I think this might be happenning because of differences in contexts? If so, how am I supposed to fix it?

```
public class AutoCompleteGOTPointAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GOTPoint> {

    Context mContext;
    List<GOTPoint> GOTPointListAll; 

    public AutoCompleteGOTPointAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<GOTPoint> GOTPointList) {
        super(context, 0, GOTPointList);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.GOTPointListAll = new ArrayList<>(GOTPointList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_line_spinner,parent,false); 
        }

        TextView textViewGOTPointName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        GOTPoint GOTPoint = this.getItem(position);

        if (GOTPoint != null) {
            textViewGOTPointName.setText(GOTPoint.getName());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                return ((GOTPoint) resultValue).getName();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                List<GOTPoint> suggestion = new ArrayList<>();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) { //
                    suggestion.addAll(GOTPointListAll);
                }
                else {
                    String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                    for (GOTPoint gotPoint : GOTPointListAll) {
                        if (gotPoint.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) { 
                            suggestion.add(gotPoint);
                        }
                    }
                }

                filterResults.values = suggestion;
                filterResults.count = suggestion.size();

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                clear();
                addAll((List) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spnMountainChains;
    AutoCompleteTextView edtEndPoint;
    AutoCompleteGOTPointAdapter GOTPointAdapter;
    List<GOTPoint> GOTPoints;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        spnMountainChains = findViewById(R.id.spn_mountain_chains);
        edtEndPoint = findViewById(R.id.actv_end_point);
        GOTPoints = new ArrayList<GOTPoint>();
        GOTPointAdapter = new AutoCompleteGOTPointAdapter( SearchActivity.this,GOTPoints);
        edtEndPoint.setAdapter(GOTPointAdapter);

        spnMountainChains.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                MountainChain mountainChain = (MountainChain) spnMountainChains.getSelectedItem();

                List<GOTPoint> filteredGOTPoints = dao.getGOTPoints(mountainChain.getId());

                GOTPointAdapter.clear();
                GOTPointAdapter.addAll(filteredGOTPoints);

//                GOTPoints.clear();            // Also doesn't work
//                GOTPoints.addAll(filteredGOTPoints); 
//                GotPointAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    }
}
```

one_line_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="21sp">
</TextView>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Unfortunately it seems that the adapter of this TextView can't be accesed from within the setOnClickListener method of another View."? Are you getting a compilation error? Or do you mean that modifications that you're doing in `onItemSelected()` aren't having any effect?

Comment: @MikeM.  Modifications aren't having effect.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm thinking that the issue is the `GOTPointListAll` and your custom `Filter`. No matter which way you `clear()`/`addAll()` in `onItemSelected()`, the `GOTPointListAll` list is never changed from what it was initialized to, so whenever the `Adapter` is filtered, all of the old items are what's being added to the results list. I don't use `AutoCompleteTextView` much, and I'm not sure of the exact behavior you're observing, but that's gotta be at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to @MikeM. comment I managed to get a solution. The problem was indeed not changing `GOTPointsListAll` after initialization. To change it whenever an item is chosen from spinner I had to do a couple of things:

- add `GOTPointList` attribute to adapter class and initialize it in constructor:

  ```
      Context mContext;
      List<GOTPoint> GOTPointListAll;
      List<GOTPoint> GOTPointList;

      public AutoCompleteGOTPointAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<GOTPoint> GOTPointList) {
          super(context, 0, GOTPointList);
          this.mContext = context;
          this.GOTPointList = GOTPointLi
          this.GOTPointListAll = new ArrayList<>(GOTPointList);
      }
  ```

  - override `notifyDataSetChanged` method of my adapter:

  ```
      @Override
      public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
          GOTPointListAll.clear();
          GOTPointListAll.addAll(GOTPointList);
          notifyDataSetChangedSuper();
      }
  ```

where

- `notifyDataSetChangedSuper` is:

  ```
      private void notifyDataSetChangedSuper() {
          super.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  ```

I should probably put operations on `GOTPoinListAll` to another function instead of overriding the existing one but it's a detail. The reason behind having those two functions is that the `GOTPointListAll` needs to be updated **only** when spinner item is selected, and `GOTPointList` needs to be updated **always** when filtration is done. That's why:

- in `publishResults()` part:

```
    clear();
    addAll((List) results.values);
    notifyDataSetChangedSuper();
```

should be changed to:

```
    GOTPointList.clear();
    GOTPointList.addAll((List) results.values);
    notifyDataSetChangedSuper();
```

- and finally in `onItemSelected()`:

```
    GOTPoints.clear();
    GOTPoints.addAll(filteredGOTPoints);
    GOTPointAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks for help!